# Flutter: scale and scroll at the same time

Tags: flutter

How can i achieve something like in the picture?

I am trying to achieve something similar with the code below, but it does not detect both scale and scroll at the same time, only one at a time.

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  double height = 400;
  double initialHeight = 400;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onScaleUpdate: (details) {
          double h = initialHeight * details.scale;

          if (h > 400 && h < 2000) {
            height = h;
          }

          setState(() {});
        },
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.amber,
            width: double.infinity,
            height: height,
            child: Text(height.toString()),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  late ScrollController _verticalScrollController;

  static const double _defaultHourHeightRatio = 60;
  double _hourHeightRatio = _defaultHourHeightRatio;
  double _totalHeight = 24 * _defaultHourHeightRatio;
  double _minuteHeightRatio = _defaultHourHeightRatio / 60;

  //Scaling variables
  double _scaleFactor = 1.0;
  double _baseScaleFactor = 1.0;
  double _baseScrollPosition = 0;
  int _scalableGridPointerDownCount = 0;
  bool _isScaleUpdating = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _verticalScrollController = ScrollController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _verticalScrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: GestureDetector(
            onScaleStart: (details) {
              if (details.pointerCount == 2) {
                _baseScaleFactor = _scaleFactor;
                _baseScrollPosition = (_verticalScrollController.offset +
                    details.localFocalPoint.dy -
                    (_hourHeightRatio - _defaultHourHeightRatio));
              }
            },
            onScaleUpdate: (details) {
              //Update only if two pointers are being used
              if (details.pointerCount == 2) {
                //Start: Change Hour Height Ratio based on scale
                _scaleFactor = min(_baseScaleFactor * details.scale, 2.5);
                _scaleFactor = max(_scaleFactor, 1);
                final hourHeightRatio =
                    (_scaleFactor * _defaultHourHeightRatio);

                if (hourHeightRatio == _hourHeightRatio) {
                  //Return if no change in ratio
                  return;
                }

                //Set the state with new hour height ratio
                setState(() {
                  _hourHeightRatio = hourHeightRatio;
                  _totalHeight = 24 * hourHeightRatio;
                  _minuteHeightRatio = hourHeightRatio / 60;
                });
                //End: Change Hour Height Ratio based on scale

                //Start: Change scroll position to keep up with pointers' dy and scale
                //Calculate scrollPosition with edge/sanity checks
                final double scrollPosition = min(
                  max(
                      (((_baseScrollPosition - details.localFocalPoint.dy) +
                              (hourHeightRatio - _defaultHourHeightRatio)) *
                          details.scale),
                      0),
                  _verticalScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
                );

                //Jump scroller to new position
                _verticalScrollController.jumpTo(scrollPosition);
                //End: Change scroll position to keep up with pointers' dy and scale
              }
            },
            child: Listener(
              onPointerDown: (event) {
                _scalableGridPointerDownCount++;
                if (!_isScaleUpdating && _scalableGridPointerDownCount > 1) {
                  setState(() {
                    _isScaleUpdating = true;
                  });
                }
              },
              onPointerCancel: (event) {
                _scalableGridPointerDownCount--;
              },
              onPointerUp: (event) {
                _scalableGridPointerDownCount--;
                if (_isScaleUpdating && _scalableGridPointerDownCount < 2) {
                  setState(() {
                    _isScaleUpdating = false;
                  });
                }
              },
              child: IgnorePointer(
                ignoring: _isScaleUpdating,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    controller: _verticalScrollController,
                    physics: _isScaleUpdating
                        ? const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
                        : null,
                    child: Container(
                      key: ValueKey(_totalHeight),
                      color: Colors.amber,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: _totalHeight,
                      child: Column(children: [
                        //TODO: Use _hourHeightRatio as height per each hour
                      ]),
                    )),
              ),
            )));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**